# Creating a three dimensional array from a data frame in R

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I have radar data in a 2D data frame with 3600 rows and 800 columns that I need to convert to a 3D array with 10 rows, 360 columns, and 800 levels. I need to split the 3600 rows into 10 groups of 360 and convert the 800 columns into the levels for the new array. So, instead of-

```
> dim(REF)
[1] 3600  800
```

I need to put the values into the form-

```
> dim(ref.array)
[1]  10 360 800
```

I know this is a pretty basic request, but I can't remember much because I haven't used R much since I took the class two years ago. Any help would be appreciated.

***Edit to answer questions below.***

If we take the example that @BondedDust used, we get the following-

```
d <- as.data.frame( matrix( 1:(3*4*5), 12, 5))
array( unlist(d), dim=c(3, 4, 5) ) 

, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   13   16   19   22
[2,]   14   17   20   23
[3,]   15   18   21   24

, , 3

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   25   28   31   34
[2,]   26   29   32   35
[3,]   27   30   33   36

, , 4

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   37   40   43   46
[2,]   38   41   44   47
[3,]   39   42   45   48

, , 5

         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   49   52   55   58
[2,]   50   53   56   59
[3,]   51   54   57   60
```

What I'm looking for is an array organized like this-

```
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3   4
[2,]    5    6    7   8
[3,]    9    10   11  12

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   13   14   15   16
[2,]   17   18   19   20
[3,]   21   22   23   24

, , 3

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   25   26   27   28
[2,]   29   30   31   32
[3,]   33   34   35   36

, , 4

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   37   38   39   40
[2,]   41   42   43   44
[3,]   45   46   47   48

, , 5

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   49   50   51   52
[2,]   53   54   55   56
[3,]   57   58   59   60
```

Comment: Some variation of this approach `simplify2array(lapply(1:ncol(REF), function(x) matrix(REF[,x], nrow=10)))` or `sapply(1:ncol(REF), function(x) matrix(REF[,x], nrow=10), simplify="array")` could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't this do it?

```
 new.arr <- array( unlist(dfrm), dim=c(10, 360, 800) ) )
```

This is what I understood to be the task, but if it is not, then there is an `aperm` function in the 'aperm' package that will allow "permuting" the dimensions:

```
d <- as.data.frame( matrix( 1:(3*4*5), 12, 5))
array( unlist(d), dim=c(3, 4, 5) ) 

##=========result============##
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   13   16   19   22
[2,]   14   17   20   23
[3,]   15   18   21   24

, , 3
snipped rest of output
```

Since it is now clear that you did want the array equivalent of byrow=TRUE (which is not an option in the R array function),  then this provides the desired result:

```
 aperm( array( unlist(d), dim=c(4, 3, 5) ) , c(2,1,3) )
#===============
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   13   14   15   16
[2,]   17   18   19   20
[3,]   21   22   23   24

Snipped rest of output.
```

I was mistaken about `aperm` being in a different package.

Comment: If `ref` is a data frame, converting to a matrix will really speed things along:  `array( unlist(as.matrix(dfrm)), dim=c(10, 360, 800) ) )`.  If `ref` is a matrix to start with, then this solution is faster, as is, than the ones in my comment.

Comment: That did work, but it is organizing the data by row rather than by column. Do you know if there's a "byrow= FALSE" type of argument for arrays?

Comment: It would help if you created a small example with 12 rows and 5 columns and said what you actually wnat to see. R is column major in its ordering of matrices and arrays so I was not expecting to need byrow=FALSE. It _should have filled the  first column (first slice of third dim)  with the first ten items from the first columnof the data frame, the next column (same third dim) with the following ten items and so on.

Comment: @BondedDust I added a better description to the question up top. Thank you for being so patient and for your help.